# adb.exe spawning many process instances

Tags: android, adb

I'm new to developing for Android and have been tasked with helping the development of some React Native based Android application. I have a working setup in which an emulated Android device can run this application. However, when starting the emulator, the process `adb.exe` repeatedly gets spawned in the background at a rate of about 1 process per second. These processes seemingly take no/very little memory (144K according to the Task Manager), but over time, this still adds up to a massive list of processes (nearing 3000 at the time of writing) taking up quite a bit of memory (which is already scarce thanks to a fairly heavy development toolchain).

Closing the emulator does not automatically terminate these processes. The only way I have found so far that works is by using `taskkill /IM /F`.

Is this expected behaviour? If not, how could I begin with tracking down the reasons for behaviour.

Comment: probably a conflict of multiple ADB installations

Comment: @VladMatvienko, Thank you for your reply! I setup my environment by performing a fresh install of Android Studio 3.0.1. Furthermore, I let Android Studio download two Android SDK versions: 26 & 27 (Oreo 8.0 & API 27 I believe?). I have one virtual device configured running Oreo 8.0. Under `AppData/Local/Android/` I have only one `Sdk` directory. In this directory, the `platform-tools` dir contains `adb.exe`. I can't see any other instances. How could I trace such a conflict?

Comment: I also encounter this problem periodically and have to `taskkill /F /IM adb.exe /T`. This is the only post I can find where someone has the same issue. I also do not have more than one copy of `adb.exe`.

Comment: You could also end the emulator.exe or qemu-system-i386.exe process that will kill all adb.exe instances. This does however seem like Android bug, a clean solution/answer needs to be posted here.

Comment: I have 490 instances of `adb.exe` running but no emuiator is running. I just used the `taskkill` command of @torchhound (thanks!) to clean the slate. I feel like it's going to recur, though, so, as @MG Developer says, it's a bug; post fix/workaround/upgrade/whatever somewhere soon!

Comment: Yeah, the 490 grew to 898. I closed AS 3.1.2 and had task manager end process for the emulator and similarly-named items. All the `adb.exe` remained until I killed all with `taskkill`.

Comment: Was anyone ever able to come up with a solution to this? I am facing the exact same problem on AS 3.2.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: For what it's worth, this also happens with Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 7.

Answer (score -3):

If that happens again try to find in task manager, there will be numerous adb.exe processes popping-up most of them with same memory usage.Lookout for a process which uses different amount of memory once you identify it dont make any changes to that one instead stop processes that display same memory usage if you even kill one of those whole stack of them will come down to one adb.exe process. i've faced a similar issue and doing this has solved the problem. generally, it happens when you start to run emulator thats when you need to see the taskmanager.